# Confusion over Eclipse SWT ViewPart and its Toolbars?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I followed roughly the recipe in this blog entry 
http://eclipsercptutorials.blogspot.com/2009/05/add-toolbar-to-view-in-eclipse-rcp.html

Which looks like that — the image appears left to the minimize/maximize icons

[image]

The thing is, if I don't assign an image to the action, then the item doesn't appear in the header, but in a separate toolbar!

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 5):

What I know is the action bar icons appear next to the minimize/maximize icons if they can fit, and appear below them if not. I did not experience the phenomenon you describe, but it's common practice to have only icons in view action bars. I recommend reading the [Eclipse UI Guidelines](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User_Interface_Guidelines).

Comment: Plus, the behavior may vary between platforms and Eclipse versions (e.g. on OS X, SWT Cocoa and SWT Carbon will behave differently).

Comment: So it is essentially not possible to determine how exactly the GUI will behave? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: And plus... even if you have only icon and the icon is too big or there are too many icons, you will see them also in new line.

Comment: @nanda That's what I said exactly. :)